# Python3 shell crashes on Windows, when trying to use non-ascii characters if I set code page to cp65001

Tags: windows, python-3.x, character-encoding

```
chcp 65001
```

...

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit  (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> s = 'ф'
```

crashes with no error info supplied, how to fix this?

Comment: That's not a crash; it's a bug in the console host process (conhost.exe in Windows 7+) that causes `ReadFile` to report successfully reading 0 bytes, i.e. End-Of-File (`EOF`), to Python's REPL, which exits the same as if you had entered `Ctrl+Z`.

Comment: The only multibyte codepages the console handles are the double-byte codepages for East-Asian text, and even that requires restarting Windows with the DBCS codepage set as the system ANSI codepage. Otherwise the console assumes 1 byte per ANSI/OEM character when converting between its native wide-character strings and the codepage that's used with the ANSI API (i.e. `ReadFile`, `ReadConsoleA`). This assumption leads to several bugs when reading from and writing to the console using codepage 65001 (UTF-8), which has 1 to 4 bytes per character.

Comment: The solution is to use the native wide-character APIs `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`. Try [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).